# Pandas groupby and add count

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to add a count of the grouped rows with my groupby.
Example:

```
name, amount
test, 1
test2, 5
test, 3
test3, 8
test2, 4
test, 1
```

Should give:

```
name, amount, count
test, 5, 3
test2, 9, 2
test3, 8, 1
```

My current groupby statements:

```
df = (df.groupby('name')['amount'].sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='name', ascending=True))
...
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['name'], 
           bins=[0,1,2], 
           labels=['A', 'B']))['amount'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: `df.groupby('name')['amount'].agg(['sum', 'count'])`

Comment: ^ this, or `df.pivot_table(index='name', values='amount', aggfunc=['count', 'sum'] ) `